# exercicio python

Tags: python, python-3.x, fórmula

A CBF (Confederação brasileira de futebol) deseja ter um programa para analisar o desempenho dos clubes que participam do campeonato brasileiro. Para isso, criou um desafio para os estudantes de computação: Criar um algoritmo que a ajude nesta tarefa. Sabendo disso, crie um programa que receba dois números inteiros do usuário: O primeiro é o número de gols feitos por uma determinada equipe no campeonato, e o segundo é o número de gols sofridos. Visto que o saldo de gols é a diferença entre o número de gols feitos e gols sofridos, e que o campeonato tem 38 jogos, calcule a média do saldo de gols de cada equipe por jogo.

**Entrada**

A entrada deverá receber dois números inteiros e maiores que zero.

**Saída**

A saída deverá mostrar a média do saldo de gols da equipe com precisão de duas casas decimais

Answer (score -3, accepted):

A resolução é bem tranquila, o texto que confunde.

Para solucionar este desafio, podemos criar uma uma função que recebe os dois números inteiros de entrada e retorna o valor da média do saldo de gols por jogo. Para calcular o saldo de gols, basta subtrair o número de gols sofridos pelo número de gols feitos. Em seguida, basta dividir o saldo de gols pelo número de jogos (38) e arredondar o resultado para duas casas decimais.

Segue a minha resolução:

```
def media_saldo_gols(gols_feitos, gols_sofridos):
  saldo_gols = gols_feitos - gols_sofridos
  media = round(saldo_gols / 38, 2)
  return media
```

Depois, você tem que testar se está tudo funcionando, então basta chamar a função e passar dois números. Segue exemplo:

```
print(media_saldo_gols(45, 30)) # deve imprimir 0.81
print(media_saldo_gols(60, 40)) # deve imprimir 1.08
print(media_saldo_gols(35, 50)) # deve imprimir -0.53
```